# Troubleshoot Attribute Rule to Update Parent Table

Tags: arcgis-pro, table, relates, arcade

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2.1 and working with an Arcade expression to update a parent layer when new inspections are performed in the related table.

I have tried a 1:M relationship class with GlobalIDs, GlobalID to GUID, and ObjectID to Object ID (original way table was related). When I select a point and attempt to add a row to the related table, the parent table is not updated. I get no errors.

````
var parent_id = $feature.parentglobalid ;
parent_id = Upper(parent_id);


var parent_class = FeatureSetByName($datastore, "hydrantCopy", ["GlobalID", 'class'], false);
var parent_records = Filter(parent_class, "GlobalID = @parent_id");

var updates = [];
var i = 0;
var new_value = '';

if ($feature.GPM >= 1500) {
new_value = "Blue - 1500 GPM or Greater";
}
else if ($feature.GPM >= 1000) {
new_value = "Green - 1000-1499 GPM";
}
else if ($feature.GPM >= 500){
new_value = "Orange - 500-999 GPM";
}
else {
new_value = "Red - 0-499 GPM";
}

 

for (var row in parent_records) {
// If the parent row is null or has a different value, updated it
if (IsEmpty(row['class']) || row['class'] != new_value)
{
updates[i++] = {
'GlobalID': parent_id,
'attributes': {"class": new_value}
};
}
}


return {
'result': parent_id,
'edit': [
{'className': 'hydrantCopy',
'updates': updates
}
]
};```
````